# How DNS learn all domains and appropriate IP adresses

Tags: networking, dns, domain

Assume that I host some web app at "some.unknown.domain.f". If I type it in web explorer, I will get appropriate response. DNS translated domain name to appropriate IP. But how does the DNS learn all the existing domains and it's IP adresses?

Who say to some DNS that new domain is created or deleted? If it's any hosting, then how can we be sure this hosting doesnt lie and give valid records for DNS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS is not a single entity – it's a lot like web, in that each domain's owner controls their own DNS record hosting. (Though most of them just use the free DNS hosting of their registrar or some CDN.)

When you register a domain, DNS as a whole doesn't need to "learn" it, only the parent domain needs to. For example, the registrar that sells you a .com domain will also provide information to the .com registry that "DNS records for example.com are hosted at ns1.godaddy.com". (This automatically covers subdomains.)

Similarly, when you update IP addresses or create subdomains, this doesn't affect DNS globally – it's stored on your DNS hosting only; e.g. if you're using Google Domains with its built-in DNS hosting, you're only updating the Google Domains servers.

(This means that "DNS propagation" is a bit of a lie, mostly.)

> how can we be sure this hosting doesnt lie

Mostly it's business contracts. It's the same as what prevents a web hosting company from taking your money and replacing your website with an ad for your competitor.

The registrar that sells you the domain has a contract with you, *and* with each TLD's registry (e.g. Verisign is the registry that oversees all of .com) – the latter is how the registrar gains access to upload nameserver information for newly registered domains into the TLD, but also requires them to not submit fake data. ("Registrar shall be responsible for verifying the accuracy of the data submitted to the Registry Operator".)

Comment: So if I host some web app at e.g. `sub.example.com`, then my hosting sends info to some root DNS server `.com` and says to it: "DNS records for example.com are hosted at ns1.ex.com", and then says to `ns1.ex.com` that records for one-level subdomains of `example.com` like `sub.example.com` are available at `sub.ns1.ex.com`. Do I understand well? If yes, which server is the root server?

Comment: Mostly correct, but subdomains are _not required_ to be on a separate nameserver – once the whole `example.com` gets delegated to `ns1.ex.com`, it can (and usually will) directly handle records for all of its subdomains, in addition to the domain itself. It's relatively rare for a domain owner to further delegate subdomains to yet another nameserver (though you _can_ do so if you want – delegation is done just by inserting `NS` records).

Comment: The DNS root is `.` and its servers are `[a-m].root-servers.net`, [see here](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/servers) and [here](https://root-servers.org/). Resolvers are usually pre-configured to know the IP addresses of the root servers as their starting point.

Comment: @Szyszka947: My additional suggestions would be to 1) poke around with the `dnstracer` tool: `dnstracer -s . www.example.com` to show the chain of delegations (there's an online version at https://freedns.afraid.org/ top-right corner); 2) get a spare domain name and try to set up _your own_ nameserver (e.g. installing Bind9 or Knot on your VPS), either by delegating the whole domain to it via registrar "nameserver" settings, and/or by delegating just a subdomain by adding NS records.

Answer (score 0):

ICANN (Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers, a non profit organization managing the internet) manages the DNS system which consists of decentralized root servers.

When you register a domain (with a domain register) they publish for you the DNS records for that domain.